Send Email(Gmail)- SMTP- C#
I want to send an email using SMTP[in c#]. And based on what I understood, I wrote such  this code.
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start......*******");
            SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Port = 587,
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
                {
                    UserName = "myGmail@gmail.com",
                    Password = "myPassword",
                }
            };
            MailAddress TestFrom = new MailAddress("myGmail@gmail.com");
            MailAddress TestTo = new MailAddress("hisGmail@gmail.com");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
            {
                From = TestFrom,
                Subject = "Subject test",
                Body = "Body test",

            };
            message.To.Add(TestTo);
            c.Send(message);


            Console.WriteLine("END*****");
        }
    }

But it threw an exception and didn't work...
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. For more information, go to'
And I realized that I need to turn on the option for "Less Secure app access" in my gmail account settings.
But it seems like such an option has  been removed by Gmail.*****
In continuation, I realized there's an alternative solution for it which should be in the "app password" section of my account's security settings. However, unfortunately, this section has been recently removed from the Gmail service, and now I'm at a dead end.
So what is the solution now and How can I send an email in C# ?!?

NO "App Password" in 2Step Verification

Not directly related to the question, but FYI: Microsoft recommends NOT to use the built-in SmtpClient but use MailKit instead.

Gmail requires SMTP to use an App Password, not the main account password https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB

@Mushroomator
I encountered the same error with Mailkit. If you have a solution, please provide it in the form of code.

@Charlieface
Your solution seems a bit outdated as I do not have these parts that are in this link in my account.

You need 2 step verification switched on. "If you’ve set up 2-Step Verification but can’t find the option to add an app password, it might be because: Your Google Account has 2-Step Verification set up only for security keys. You’re logged into a work, school or another organisation account. Your Google Account has Advanced Protection."
